# how to organize divs for a specific layout

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a section that will have preview thumbnails, and that when a preview is clicked, a div containing extended content related to that section will be opened in the same page.  Here is an illustration:

[image]

I want the extended div to push down the thumbnail divs on the row below it, as per the illustration.

[**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/eyalbin/FqLhz/8/) is a simplified fiddle with wrong generated configuration

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="extended"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.preview {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #c35;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.preview:hover {
    background: #f90;
}
.extended {
    width: 152px;
    height: 0;
    display: none;
    background: #f90;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.preview').click(function () {            
        $('div.extended').css('height', 50);
        $('div.extended').css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

Can anyone help me get this right?

Comment: Like this? http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/

Comment: EXACTLY like this :-)

Comment: is this ok http://jsfiddle.net/FqLhz/10/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change the DOM position of the extended elements, then this will work. I've assigned two [custom attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) which are *valid as of HTML5*, and changed your DOM a bit, so that by clicking on the relevant `div`, you will get the appropriate collapsed content.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FqLhz/12/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/FqLhz/23/) *(Persisting active state)*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.preview').click(function () {
        $('div.extended').css({'display':'none'});
        $('div.extended[data-preview="'+ $(this).attr('data-bind') +'"]').css({'display':'block'});
    });
});
```

Comment: this is a very good solution, the only problem is that the divs are generated automatically by wordpress query so I don't know how to add the data-bind/data-preview autonatically or if it is even possible...

Comment: Such questions are normally answered by looking into the code that generates that stuff and if at that location some filters are called to influence that. That should normally do it if you find one (there are pretty many but not always a needed one). If there is no filter, you can hack and suggest one to add there (try but do not expect too much, ticket overflow in WP) -or- you work with output filtering/HTML-fragmens and manipulate via DOM on a fragment or the whole output. Because somewhere is a filter.

Comment: @EyalBinehaker Thank you, not sure about the wordpress part though, but you can follow this method and throw another question for the wordpress solution ---- aaaa here comes my savior ... read his comment

Comment: And looking into works best with xdebug. Wordpress has not too much code, but perhaps it's not really clear where the code walks. With xdebug as a step-debugger this normally becomes a breeze. Works 10 times faster as var_dumping your way through.

Comment: @Mr.Alien  thanks but cant make upvote twice.. :P :D

Answer (score 1):

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FqLhz/20/) :: Then you should put the extended div after three preview divs like:

```
<div class="preview"></div>
<div class="preview"></div>
<div class="preview"></div>
<div class="extended"></div>
```

And then handle dynamically the link between preview and extended.

Comment: Just if you can something like this will make me vote your answer http://jsfiddle.net/FqLhz/18/ :) as you do toggle the elements, but they aren't collapsed when the other one is switched

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `extended` div after 3 `preview` divs. It works fine.

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pqqJx/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want it to overlap the divs below it instead of pushing them down? In that case, use `position: absolute` on the `extended` div, and instead of hiding it with `height:0`, hide it with `display:none` changing it to `display:block` when you want to reveal it. This way, it will overlap the existing preview divs.

Comment: Oh - then I think the phrasing of the question may be wrong. "I am struggling to understand how can I make the extended div NOT to push the other preview divs that are after it below it" - that implies he doesn't want to push them, surely?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you all and thanks for your help :)